# Error with list.dirs in R kept poping up no matter what I type

Tags: r, list, rstudio, error-messaging

I first developed my R script in R version 3.3.1 and R Studio 1.0.143, everything worked fine and the R library has a build-in function list.dirs(path = direct1, recursive = FALSE) to help me list directories.

Then I have to downgrade R to version 2.1.3 because of the compatibility requirement with my co-workers.The function list.dirs was not build-in anymore, so I had to write a function for it to list directories. The function I wrote is not related to the problem as later I added more for-loops to replace the necessity of list.dirs().

Then no matter what I type in the command, this error message kept popping up, even I have an empty script open or without any function related to list.dirs().

```
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
Error in list.dirs(dir, full.names = full.names, recursive = recursive) : 
  unused argument(s) (recursive = recursive)
```

It is annoying to see it coming up all the time, although I can run my script normally.

Is there any method to stop this error message?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing should be resolved with [RStudio v1.0.153](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/).